# Writing textField input to file

Tags: java, textfield, file-writing

I am trying to get input from several text fields and to add these as a list in my stock file when a button is pressed. When I test it, it just empties my stock file.

```
    JButton btnAddProduct = new JButton("Add Product");
    btnAddProduct.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text0 = textbarcode.getText();
            String text1 = textdeviceName.getText();
            String text2 = textdeviceType.getText();
            String text3 = textbrand.getText();
            String text4 = textcolour.getText();
            String text5 = textconnectivity.getText();
            String text6 = textquantity.getText();
            String text7 = textoriginalCost.getText();
            String text8 = textretailPrice.getText();
            String text9 = textadditionalInformation.getText();
            textbarcode.setText("");
            textdeviceName.setText("");
            textdeviceType.setText("");
            textbrand.setText("");
            textcolour.setText("");
            textconnectivity.setText("");
            textquantity.setText("");
            textoriginalCost.setText("");
            textretailPrice.setText("");
            textadditionalInformation.setText("");
            
            String text = (text0 + text1 + text2 + text3 + text4 + text5 + text6 + text7 + text8 + text9);
           
            try {
                new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Stock.txt")).write(text);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        
    });

    btnAddProduct.setBounds(720, 367, 200, 37);
    panelAddProduct.add(btnAddProduct);
```

Comment: Try closing the writer to ensure the data is written.

Comment: *I am trying to get input from several text fields and to add these as a list in my stock file* Your text will be written as a single string and you will not be able to parse it when you attempt to read the data later.  I suggest instead of using String concatenation, you can use a `StringJoiner` to add a delimiter between each individual string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is each time you create `new FileWriter("Stock.txt")` you are creating a new file or overwriting an exisiting file.

To solve the problem, use `new FileWriter("Stock.txt", true)` so it looks like this:

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Stock.txt", true)).write(text);
```

Also, close the `BufferedWriter` with the `close()` method. So it's maybe a better idea to assign the `new BufferedWriter()` object to a variable to `close()` after writing.

Hope that solves the problem :D